# Is it possible to edit a second level into Grub, for dual-boot loaders?

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, grub2, shortcuts

To clarify, I want to have Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7 as the only two options on the boot menu, but still be able to access the memtest options that come up if I am quick enough to press F8 or something before the countdown occurs, bringing up a second level instead of booting into .

Using "sudo nano -B", I can change the default option to 3 (or whichever option it is), or set it to saved, and Grub will remember which os I choose at that boot when I know I'll be restarting often for updates that require restarts.

Using "gksu gedit /etc/default/grub", I can comment out the options I don't want on the first load page, but that removes access to the options I still might want/need.

What I want to know is how I can ad a second level that reacts to "F8" (or some other such shortcut, to access the options I don't want to see on the first level. Can anyone help me to learn how to edit "gksu gedit /etc/default/grub" further to attain this?